# "Lock" option not available in the report filters of classic environment

Tags: reporting, filters

Salesforce classic environment does not have the option to lock the filters in the report but in the lightning environment we can lock them.

What is the way to lock the filters of the report in the classic or is there any specific reason salesforce does not provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic you can only filter your report from the report builder but cannot lock and currently there is no workaround.

Classic reports are only in support mode and lightning is where the new innovation is happening.

The recommendation would be please use lightning experience.  Below are a few points about reports in lightning.

> > Lightning has the formatted export option which is far better than the printable view in classic.  Also, it provides new ways of grouping data easily
> >     With Lightning you can now add more 12 reports in one row compared to the classic where you can only display 3 reports in one row.
> >     Report formula editor in lightning is much better compared to classic

Review below article which clearly mentions this feature is available in lightning only.

[Filter Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_builder_filtering.htm&type=5)

Thanks,